# RedisStore ignores host and port fields

Tags: node.js, express, node-redis

I'm using `express` and `connect-redis` to get the server to use Redis for sessions.

```
import Session from 'express-session';
const session = Session({
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  key: '...', 
  secret: '...',
  store: initializeRedis(Session);
});
```

The redis initializer looks like the following:

```
import { createClient as createRedisClient } from 'redis';
import connectRedis from 'connect-redis';

export default function initializeRedis(Session) {
  const redisClient = createRedisClient();
  const RedisStore = connectRedis(Session);
  return new RedisStore({
    host: 'redis',
    port: 6378,
  });
}
```

According to the previous [option parameters](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis#options), the server should be connecting to `redis` instead of the default `127.0.0.1` through port `6378` instead of the default `6379`

However, regardless of what these values equal to I always get the same output:

> Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect
>   ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

Is there anything I missed out during the configuration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## TL;DR

The Redis client was missing the `host` and `port` parameters. There was no client inside the `RedisStore`.

```
const redisClient = createRedisClient({
  host: 'redis',
  port: 6379
});

return new RedisStore({
  client: redisClient,
});
```

*Full copy-paste'able code at the end of the post, in case it is useful for anyone else.*

## Full version

There were a couple ways to solve the code above.

**1. The `const redisClient = createRedisClient()` was assigned nowhere**, but it was still doing its connecting job. Hence, the server was crashing because it could not connect, but it was not a `RedisStore` fault.

At the time I posted the question, I didn't notice that line was there and I thought it was crashing due to the store.

In fact, without that line it works, because the [RedisStore has a default client implementation](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis#options).

> or
>   created for you using the host, port, or socket params.

```
  return new RedisStore({
    host: 'redis',
    port: 6379,
  });
```

**2. The redis client was missing the host and port custom values** (default values are `'127.0.0.1'` and `6379`)

```
  import { createClient as createRedisClient } from 'redis';
  const redisClient = createRedisClient({
    host: 'redis',
    port: 6379
  });
```

If we are using a specific client implementation, it also makes sense that we pass it into the `RedisStore`:

```
  const RedisStore = connectRedis(Session);
  return new RedisStore({
    client: redisClient,
  });
```

## Full takeaway code

server.js

```
import Session from 'express-session';
import initializeRedis from './redis';

// Initialize session.
const session = Session({
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  key: 'SID',
  secret: 'Luke Skywalker',
  store: initializeRedis(Session)
});
app.use(session);
```

redis.js

```
import { createClient as createRedisClient } from 'redis';
import connectRedis from 'connect-redis';

export default function initializeRedis(Session) {
  const redisClient = createRedisClient({
    host: 'redis', // or '127.0.0.1'.
    port: 6379,
  });
  const RedisStore = connectRedis(Session);
  return new RedisStore({ client: redisClient });
}
```